# How to apply 301 redirect to link that no longer exists because record was deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I delete a product from the database, the link associated with it no longer works and returns a 404 error such as

https://www.luminoto.com/wallpapers/burnt-down-forrest-ca-2006

In rails, how can I make sure that all deleted products get redirected to my homepage saying that product longer exists?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like:

```
class ProductsController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found

  private def record_not_found
    redirect_to controller: 'home', action: 'index', alert: 'Product no longer exists'
  end
end
```

Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue-from for more info.

Comment: works great.  I put this in my application controller to take care of invalid records for other models as well (users, categories, etc) .  Any reason I shouldnt do this?

Comment: I also put a 301 redirect using    redirect_to root_url, :status => 301

Comment: Yes, if you put on your `ApplicationController`, it will work for all your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

if its just a matter of showing link which actually do not work..you can use [link_to_if](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if)

**Creates a link tag of the given name using a URL created by the set of options if condition is true, otherwise only the name is returned.**

```
<%= link_to_if(@product.present?, "Show More", { controller: "sessions", action: "new" }) %>
```